# Should `super()` return `this` even for functions?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I've found a difference in behavior between normal browsers and Edge. When you inherit from a function instead of a class, `super()` returns `undefined` under Edge.

```
const f = function () {};
class g extends f {
    constructor() {
        if (super()) {
            document.body.innerHTML = 'Sane browser';
        }
    }
}
new g();
```

[Live version.](https://jsfiddle.net/4d2zkrun/)

Which behavior is correct?

Answer (score -1):

constructors are not responsible of creating pointer of the object. 
'new' operator however, creates a blank object and its responsible of assigning this pointer inside constructor.

Actually, constructors are not real constructors until they are called with new operator. They are just functions